# How to get filtered VM list on vcenter with python

Tags: python, vmware, vcenter, pyvmomi, pysphere

I'm trying to get a list of registered virtual machines - by their name - in my vcenter. The problem that I have many vms (~5K), and I am doing it a lot of times (O(1000)/hour).

The SDKs I'm using causing it a lot of traffic (1-2MB/request):

1. `pysphere`: which ask for all vms, and filters on client side.
2. `pyVmomi`, which need to use recursion to list all vms (I saw `SI.content.searchIndex.FindByDnsName` on [reboot_vm.py](https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/reboot_vm.py), but my machines' DNS configuration is not true)

Looking into SOAP documentation didn't help (got into `RetrievePropertiesEx.objectSet` but it doesn't looks to filter anything), and the new REST (v6.5) didn't help too (since I need to get its "datastore path", and all I can get is the name)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried a using a property collector, as in `pyVmomi.vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.FilterSpec`?

The pyVmomi Community Samples contain examples of using this API, such as
https://github.com/vmware/pyvmomi-community-samples/blob/master/samples/filter_vms.py.

Comment: From what I see, the example codes in the link still have to retrieve all vms, then use a for-loop to match filters, which does not improve efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

vAPI is based on REST, even more, it does network requests every time, so it will be slow. Another way is to use VCDB, where are stored all VMs (there us such one, but I can not help you here more), see https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.installclassic.doc_41/install/prep_db/c_preparing_the_vmware_infrastructure_databases.html or https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1025914